# Using Storyboard while Programmatically-Creating UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I want to programmatically create a UITableViewController, using a TableView that I create in a storyboard where I name the storyboard `TableViewCont.storyboard`.

Here's the code I was trying to use in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
   UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"TableViewCont" bundle:bundle];
   self.window.rootViewController = tvc;
   return YES;
}
```

There's no syntax error reported but the TableViewController doesn't show when I run the app on my device. I know `UITableViewController` functions differently than `UIViewController` when you initialize with `initWithNib:bundle:` but I'm lost as to why this code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an **initWithNib** in your storyboard. This is for the xib files.

To initialize a controller from the storyboard, you have to use **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**. See the below example

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TableViewCont" bundle:nil]; 

UITableViewController *tvc = (UITableViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your identifier"];
```

Dont forget to put identifier for your tableview controller in the storyboard